# AEM request forward 500

Tags: aem, sling

I have a scenario,

1. Created a sling servlet to be hit in browser.
2. Do some heavy lifting.
3. Set some attributes/parameters in slingRequest
4. Finally used requestDispatcher.forward(slingRequest,singResponse) to redirect     to a page.
5. Once landed on page, user slingRequest to get attributes/parameters and use it.

Now when i use it, i see HTTP 500 error in browser without any trace of what bad has happened.

I referred sling docs @ https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/dispatching-requests.html but no help.

Has anybody faced it ever? Any reason/remedy?

Comment: You can inspect the AEM error log to find out the root cause behind the 500.

Comment: Done, no specific loggers except its not able to go to that page.

Comment: What's the HTTP 500 error stack looking like? Can you dump a sample over here for us to look at?